# Sorting through dictonaries

Tags: python

I need help writing a function to print all of the flights specified in fromCity and toCity for all airlines.  This is the function Im using def reportAllFlightsFromTo (flightsD,fromCity,toCity):

Here is the code Ive already tried:

```
def reportAllFlightsFromTo (airD,fromCity,toCity): 
    for aLines in airD:
        print(aLines)
        newList=[]
        for flightNum in airD[aLines]:
            if airD[aLines][flightNum][0][0]==fromCity and airD[aLines][flightNum][1][0]==toCity:
                tempList=[]
                tempList.append(airD[aLines][flightNum][0][1])
                tempList.append(airD[aLines][flightNum][1][1])
                tempList.append(flightNum)
                newList.append(tempList)
        newList.sort()
        print(newList)
```

This is the dictionary I'm using:

```
flightsD={"Delta":{1102:[["IND",1850],["MDW",1955]],
                   1096:[["PHX",900],["MDW",1255]],
                   1445:[["ATL",1135],["LAX",1810]],
                   1776:[["PHL",1350],["RAP",1610]],
                   1226:[["PHX",950],["MDW",1345]],
                   1885:[["ATL",1305],["LAX",2000]],
                   1009:[["MDW",1850],["IND",1955]],
                   9001:[["MDW",2145],["IND",2255]]},
          "Southwestern":{1111:[["SAT",430],["MDW",825]],
                          2121:[["MDW",430],["SAT",825]],
                          4335:[["PHX",450],["MDW",745]],
                          1102:[["MDW",1100],["PHX",1450]]},
          "American":{7765:[["IND",1850],["CHA",2105]],
                   2133:[["BNA",900],["IND",1115]],
                   3321:[["HOU",1335],["ATL",1615]],
                   2100:[["BNA",900],["IND",1115]],
                   4311:[["HOU",905],["ATL",1255]],
                   5577:[["ATL",1100],["HOU",1350]],
                   1102:[["BNA",1100],["HOU",1450]]}  }
```

This is the result Im receiving with my current code:

```
Delta
[]
Southwestern
[]
American
[[1850, 2105, 7765]]
```

This is the result I need:

```
reportAllFlightsFromTo(flightsD,"MDW","IND")
       MDW  IND
  NUM  DEP  ARR  AIRLINE   
 1009 1850 1955  Delta     
 9001 2145 2255  Delta
```

Comment: Fix your formatting (indentation and stuff), also you didn't include enough code. What is airD?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: you should try `pandas`

Answer (score 1):

```
def reportAllFlightsFromTo(flightsD,fromCity,toCity):
    for airline_name, flights in flightsD.items():
        for flight_number, flight in flights.items():
            if flight[0][0] == fromCity and flight[1][0] == toCity:
                yield flight_number, flight[0][1], flight[1][1], airline_name

result = list(reportAllFlightsFromTo(flightsD,"MDW","IND"))

print('       MDW  IND')
print('  NUM  DEP  ARR  AIRLINE')
for i in result:
    print(' {} {} {}  {}'.format(*i))
```

**Output:**

```
       MDW  IND
  NUM  DEP  ARR  AIRLINE
 1009 1850 1955  Delta
 9001 2145 2255  Delta
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def reportFlightsFromTo(flights, src, dest):
    matching_flights = {}
    for airline, flight_dict in flights.items():
        for flight_no, flight_info in flight_dict.items():
            if flight_info[0][0] == src and flight_info[1][0] == dest:
                tmp = {flight_no:{'depart':flight_info[0][1], 'arrive':flight_info[1][1]}}
                if matching_flights.get(airline):
                    matching_flights[airline].append(tmp)
                else:
                    matching_flights[airline] = [tmp]
    return matching_flights
```

The main difference between this and Filip's answer is that Filip's function is a generator (note the use of the keyword yield). Mine will return a data structure containing the information, which you can then format as desired.

More important to note is the similarities. Namely, the use of .items() to iterate over key and value pairs in a dictionary. This avoids the long access in your code, for example `airD[aLines][flightNum][0][0]` by making the value available in the loop.